# How to have a good json format in Bash?

Tags: json, bash

I have a script wherein when I get the value I will going to output them in a json format.

Below is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if
[ "$(egrep -l 'TR.834' /home/user/for_test_dir/*) " ];
    then
        egrep -l 'TR.834' /home/user/for_test_dir/* > /tmp/outbound.txt
            chmod 777 /tmp/result.txt

#json_File=~/outboundFile.json
    info_template='
    {
    "date" : "%s",
    "time" : "%s",
    "type" : "%s", 
    "num" : "%s"
    },\n'

    echo '{' #>> $json_File
    echo -e '\t"List": {' #>> $json_File
    echo -e '\t\t"Data" : ['  #>> $json_File     



            a=1
            while read LINE
            do

                            fullpath[$a]=$LINE
                            filename[$a]=`basename $LINE`
                            cat $LINE | awk '{gsub("-",RS);print}' > /tmp/temp2.txt
                            chmod 777 /tmp/temp2.txt
                            cat /tmp/temp2.txt | awk '{gsub("*",RS);print}' > /tmp/temp.txt
                            chmod 777 /tmp/temp.txt


                                    DATE[$a]=`sed -n '10p' < /tmp/temp.txt`
                                    TIME[$a]=`sed -n '11p' < /tmp/temp.txt`
                                    TYPE[$a]=`sed -n '28p' < /tmp/temp.txt`
                                    NUM[$a]=`grep -oP 'BEN.\K[A-Z0-9_-\s]*' < /tmp/temp2.txt |  awk '{ printf "%s,", $0 }'|  sed 's/,\+$//' | awk '!x[$0]++'`       

                            printf "$template" "${DATE[$a]}"\
                                                    "${TIME[$a]}"\
                                                    "${TYPE[$a]}"\
                                                    "${num[$a]}"    #>> $json_File  

    done < /tmp/result.txt
fi

    echo -e "\t\t]" #>> $json_File
    echo -e "\t}" #>> $json_File
        echo -e "}" #>> $json_File
```

My problem here is when I extract more than one data.  Like for example, "NUM": "3232", "232343", "23345",
  and my expected output for this would be like this:

```
"NUM"  : [
       "3232",
       "232343",
       "23345"
     ]
```

For single-data, "NUM" : "23234" (format would be as is). Badly need your help.

Comment: Show your script. the answer depends on how the numbers are held in the script (e.g. array, ...) or whether you have a counter available holding the number of 'numbers' you need to output. It's hard to see your screen from here...

Comment: the `echo '['` will print `[` and the `echo ']'` will print `]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '{ "NUM": "3232", "232343", "23345" }' | python -m json.tool
```

or

```
sudo gem install json
echo '{ "NUM": "3232", "232343", "23345" }' | prettify_json.rb
```